# visible menu only for guest user in joomla

Tags: joomla, menu

I am trying to implement a menu in joomla 1.5 which should be visible only for guest user not for registered user.
For that I made changes in two files, those are `administrator/components/com_menus/models/metadata/component.xml`
and

```
modules/mod_mainmenu/helper.php
```

For the first file, I have added the following code in the line no 20:

```
<param name="show_to_guest_only" type="radio" default="0" label="Show to Guest only" description="Show menu to guest user only.">
<option value="0">No</option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
</param>
```

And for the second file, I have added the following pieces of code just before the line no 50:

```
$row_params = new JParameter($row->params);
if ($row_params->get('show_to_guest_only') == 1 && $user->id ){
continue;
}
```

But after doing this also, I am not getting the expected result.
Can you please help me how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know my comment isn't productive but Joomla! 1.5 is really old now and no longer supported.

Comment: its true. But I think some solution should be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't hack the core files. If nothing else copy mod_mainmenu to another name like mod_guestmenu and then do your changes there and installing.

You might want to use one of the advanced module management extensions available at [extensions.joomla.org](http://extensions.joomla.org)

MetaMod is one that springs to mind.

Comment: great... by making use of MetaMod I got the solution.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. It detects whether the users is a guest and also get the items of a specific menu type.

```
$user =& JFactory::getApplication();
$app =& JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$menu_items = $menu->getItems('menutype', 'mainmenu');

if ($user->guest) {
    //your code goes in here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the idea is that there are other menu's he wants to show to everyone. Hence the parameter he's using ;)